# extracting data line by line from a text file and storing it in a list in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop

I have a text file which consists of names of different countries as follows:

[image]

I have to extract all these names and store them inside a list using python.

**Python Code:**

```
with open('a.txt') as x:
    b = [word for line in x for word in line.split()]
    print(b)
```

**Problem:**
The above python codes works absolutely fine but the only problem is that if it finds any space between any 2 words, it is storing them as two separate words in a list. Whereas, I want to retrieve the names line by line and store that entire word as a single word.

**For Example:**
I want to store the word Antigua & Deps as a single word inside the list. Whereas, it is storing it as 3 different words.

Can anyone please help me out with this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can just keep the line:

```
b = [line.strip() for line in x]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can directly use `readlines` on your file handler:

```
with open('a.txt') as x:
    b = x.readlines()
```

This will have trailing newline character at the end of each line which you can avoid by:

```
with open('a.txt') as x:
    b = [line.strip() for line in x]
```

---

**Why do you get your output?**

You are doing `for word in line.split()` which infact is splitting on whitespaces in each line.

Comment: Thanks @Vivek for the suggestion. I would say descriptive names were more meaningful though.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to read line by line and you want control some thing then
you can do this code

```
List = [] 
f = open("countries.txt", "r")
for x in f:
  List.append(x.strip())

f.close()

print(List)
```

Comment: I have tried this method. But the problem is that \n is being added at the end of each element which makes things tough from the next part of the code.

Comment: add `.strip()` to the string which remove the CRLF, modified the code